# Web Pages issue with azure when servicestack is deployed

Tags: azure, f#, servicestack, asp.net-webpages, servicestack-razor

I am trying to deploy Servicestack application to azure website. Application is with asp.net host and razor view engine.

[Here](http://servicestacksignalrfsharp.azurewebsites.net/) is final deployed version. And also [github project](https://github.com/kunjee17/ServicestackSignalRFSharp)

Now, it working fine in local without any issue. But giving problem after deployment. If I forcefully load the assembly in web.config azure can't load it. And if don't do that servicestack crashed nullpointer exception.

I checked the application setting, as per it azure sites are running webpages version 3.x.x.x.

Please let me know if any further information needed.

Here is stack trace of error

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory..cctor() +336

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory' threw an exception.]
   ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory..ctor() +0

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +232
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1136
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +128
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture) +18
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[] args) +60
   System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache..ctor(String type) +46
   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetFactory(String type) +86
   System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +262
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

**[UPDATE]** I guess issue is not on servicestack side. Things are working fine if I deploy the C# version of it. 
To make compile on azure there is need to add below code in fsproj file.

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" 
        Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" 
        Condition="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I manage to solve the issue. I have put details on [my blog](http://kunjan.in/2014/03/signalr-nancy-azure-with-fsharp/).

Basically due to some weird reason I couldn't access to global.asax file. So, I moved start up code of servicestack with signalR and things started working.